# MATA-INFcontext.xml is getting override by tomcat/conf/contex.xml

Tags: tomcat, context.xml

I have a maven based application that contains META-INF/context.xml which contains the database info. I am deploying my app in tomcat-9.1 tomcat has its own conf/context.xml, tomcat context.ml file has some other database info

When i deploy my app in tomcat it is connecting to database from tomcat/conf/context.xml
I can not remove DB info`tomcat/conf/context.xml` because other apps are deployed on the same tomcat.

is there to prevent overriding META-INF/context.xml with tomcat context.xml

**This is the entry in tomcat context.xml**

```html
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/myDb" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="mydburl"
        username="username" password="pass"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

**This is entry in META-INF/context.xml**

```html
<Context>
   <Resource name="jdbc/myDb"

              closeMethod="close"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              url="myDbUrl"
              maxTotal="30"
              maxIdle="10"
              minIdle="5"
              maxWaitMillis="18000000"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              username="username"
              password="pass"
              />
</Context>
```

**There is no error in DB details i am able to connect successfully.**

**Is there anything am I missing?**

Comment: The way you ask your question, it seems not much of an issue, as both connections are largely the same, with slightly differing `max...` attributes. Please let us know where you went overboard with anonymization: Are both JNDI names "myDB"? (if yes: why? it might be as simple as naming the database according to its purpose, and not the fact that it's *a* (the app's) database)

Comment: @OlafKock all together whole database is different database